# Proving that $[\mathbb{R}, +]$ forms a group

Tags: group-theory

Is there any way to prove that $[\mathbb{R}, +]$ forms a group, without just using any two/three real numbers as an example to prove for associativity and closure? I know that you could generally prove that there is an identity and inverse for addition, just not sure what to do about associativity and closure.

Comment: Didn't you learn in elementary school that addition is associative for real numbers? (Probably not in those words, of course, but most come out of school knowing that $a+(b+c)$ makes the same as $(a+b)+c$). And that the sum of two real numbers is a real number?

Comment: It is usually assumed from basic knowledge, yet if you want to be formal first be sure *how* are that operation formally defined in your case (many times by means of limits). Another idea is to define by means of functions, say $\;f:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;f(a,b):=a+b\;$, and use previous knowledge about associativity of functions composition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That will hardly make the cut in many universities' case. One basic example is to prove *by axioms/definitions* that $\;0\cdot a=0\;$ for all $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$  in the real numbers system and with the usual definitions/axioms.

Comment: @OP Yes, it is possible. However it depends on your definition of the real numbers. How did your course define them? As norm completion of the rationals or by axioms, or somehow else?

Comment: @Joanpemo: Yes, but that's not what the OP is doing here -- in a typical  _group theory_ course one is expected to just know how the real numbers work already, even though there are _other_ courses where one investigates how the well-known properties of the reals can be formalized.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you . Yes, I think that may be the case here.

Comment: Btw, "just using any two/three real numbers as an example to prove for associativity and closure" wouldn't make it a proof, as this latter requires to show things *for every* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, if you understand exactly what associativity and closure mean, I think the proof should be straightforward.

Associativity intuitively means that you can change the order of the group operation and not change the result. To put it slightly more formally, $\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$, $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$. Now, you should notice that for all real numbers, the order of adding them together does not matter, which means the the group of real numbers under addition is associative.

Closure intuitively implies that the result of adding (since in this case, the operation is +) two elements in the group still gives you an element in the group. ie. $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}, \quad a+b \in \mathbb{R}$.
This is true for the real numbers since adding two real numbers still gives you a real number.